# Create a nested form : "undefined method `push'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to build a new Review form, but it return me an error than I don't understand. Con you explain me the problem ?

My code

routes :

```
resources :posts do 
    resources :pushs do 
      resources :reviews
    end 
  end
```

The link :

```
<%= link_to 'Add comment', new_post_push_review_path(@push.post_id, @push) %>
```

The form that I would like to built :

```
<%= simple_form_for([@post, @post.push.reviews.build]) do |f| %>

<%= f.input :rating %>
<%= f.input :comment %>
<%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

[image]

& finally, the controller review :

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_push
  before_action :find_post




  def new 
    @review = Review.new 
    @pushs = Push.all
  end 

  def create
    @push = Push.find(params[:review][:id])
    @review = Review.new(review_params)

     @review.post_id = @push.post_id
     @review.push_id = @push.id 
     @review.user_id = current_user.id

    if @review.save 
      redirect_to push_path(@push.post_id, @push)
    else 
      render 'new'
    end 
  end 

private 

  def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
  end 



   def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end 

  def find_push
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @push = @post.pushs.find(params[:push_id]) 
  end 

end
```

Well, if you have any ideas to explain me my error(s), that would be great !!

Comment: please show your `Reviews` model

Comment: May be the problem is with post model. Does it have has_one push?

Comment: Could you add your Post model please ? I particularly want to know if you have in your Post model something like : has_one :push.

Comment: No I have this into my post model :
 has_many :pushs, dependent: :destroy 
  & has_many :reviews

Comment: I have diffrents push for each post and diffrents reviews for each push

Comment: has_many :pushs is also a problem.. you may need @post.pushs[0].reviews..review is created for which push?? has_many :pushs is adding a method named pushs to post model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes, you have to change *resources :pushs do* to *resources :pushes do*

And you might not have set associations in Post, Push, Review models.

Comment: I know it for pushes, but is stil working too with pushs, I think the problem is comming from my review controller. 
And for the associations Post has_many (pushs  & reviews), Push has_many reviews, belongs_to( User & Post)

Comment: If Post has many: pushes, then you have to write `@post.pushes` instead of `@post.push`.
We have write plural form of the model name because of has_many association.
`@post.push` will be correct if it is has_one association.

Comment: Great ! This is working, but now the problem is about reviews. (undefined method `reviews' for #<Push::ActiveRecord). & push has many reviews. Where do i have to declare this variable ?

Comment: Post has many pushes and push has many reviews. So, inorder to create a review, you need post_id and push_id.
URL will be like: http://localhost:3000/posts/1/pushes/1/review/new

then your reviews#new will be like,
`def new
  @push = Push.find_by(post_id: params[:post_id])
  @review = @push.reviews.new
end`

and in view file,
`<%= simple_form_for([@push, @review], method: :post) do |f| %>`

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot man ! It's exactily what i'm looking for, you're my hero ! If someone have the same problem, for the solution, just add @post into the simple_form and it will be perfect !